# Make LAN Web Application accessible through a outside Server

Tags: webserver

There's a computer `PC1` with web application server that connected to the internet, using private IP (172.16.x.x).

I have an outside server (Linux, command line only) `PC2` that using real IP `192.211.y.y`, `PC1` can access `PC2`, but `PC2` can't access `PC1` (because it's private IP).

I believe there's an application that could enable visiting `PC1` through `PC2`, so when people visit `192.211.y.y:12124` it would show the content of `PC1:12123`, I forgot the name of that application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember now, It's [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) - Introspected tunnels to localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse proxy in apache/nginx, over a vpn

Comment: the problem with reverse proxy is the `PC2` must able to access `PC1`

Comment: Yes, I understand.. and a nginx reverse proxy could be your solution.